# javascript regex replace `"` in tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I got a string like this :

```
"{"name":"joy","tag":"<img src="/1/1.png"/>hello<img src="/1/2.png">"}"
```

I know how to match all chars between `<>` , but have no idea how to replace certain char ... I want to replace `"` with `'` .

Comment: so how did you match the text inside the < and >?

Comment: `/<.*?>/g`  this is OK @epascarello

Comment: I wonder if this can be done with one regex ?

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex!!!!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Comment: @Oriol  I just want to replace characters ...

Comment: @Oriol Please! Stop to remember each time this post, when somebody see `<` or `>` and `regex` in one sentence! It's not `HTML`, it's just `json` data! P̬l̛̝̲̦͔e̙̗̻̳̥͢ạse̜̳̠̱ ̳͍̲̜͍͉̯s̭̦̟̳̯͎͚͠t҉͕̲̪ͅo̯̭̥̻p̟̻̙!̭̼̬̦̟͕̠͞

Comment: @user3335966 It's JSON data which presumably contains HTML data. You might desire otherwise, but HTML can't be parsed with regex.

Comment: @Oriol - I wouldn't say "presumably": that is clearly HTML within the (currently invalid) JSON. But although in general parsing HTML with regex is bad, for limited, *controlled* cases it can work fine for simple string replacements. But a better solution here would be to *not* create such a string in the first place, e.g., by creating an object then stringifying it to JSON (so the double-quotes in the `tag` property would automatically be escaped appropriately), or create the HTML portion of the string with single-quotes before using it.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like

```js
var result = "{\"name\":\"joy\",\"tag\":\"<img src=\"/1/1.png\"/>hello<img src=\"/1/2.png\">\"}".replace(/<(.*?)>/g, function(a, b){
    return a.replace(/"/g, "'");
});

console.log(result);
```

and this will replace all the quotes inside the html elements for single quotes, the 'g' is to replace ALL the occurrences

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can be done this way , can not be done within one regex ?

Answer (score 1):

```
str = '{"name":"joy","tag":"<img src="/1/1.png"/>hello<img src="/1/2.png">"}';
```

*Solution 1*:

```
res = str.match(/\<[^>]+\>/g);
for(var i = 0, l = res.length; i < l; i++){
    str = str.replace(res[i], res[i].replace(/"/g, "'"));
}
```

*Solution 2*:
**!!!** This solution would be work only for one set of `""` **!!!**

```
res = str.replace(/(\<[^">]*)"([^">]*)"([^>]*\>)/g, "$1'$2'$3");
```

*Result*:

```
"{"name":"joy","tag":"<img src='/1/1.png'/>hello<img src='/1/2.png'>"}"
```

Comment: Same with @S. Garces  .

Comment: I simplified my json string , it contains more than one pair of `""` ..

Comment: @passion I mean one pair between `<>`;

Comment: @passion  I think You can't make it in single regex. 1st solution must resolve all cases with `"`;